# Appending QGraphicsItems to QGraphicsItemGroup causes crash

Tags: c++, qt

This is my first post.  I've recently started using QT with C++.  Very impressed.  I have a problem that I cannot seem to get a handle on.  Basically, I'm attempting to organize many `QGraphicsItems` into two `QGraphicsItemGroups`.  The items are displayed using a `QGraphicsScene` on a `QGraphicsView`. Creating the items and displaying the items works like a charm.  When I add the grouping, however, the program crashes on the command every time.  The reason for adding the groupings is to later be able to choose which items to render in the paintevent.  The relevant code is listed below.

```
QGraphicsScene * scene;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui.graphicsView->setScene(scene);

QBrush whiteBrush;
QBrush imageBrush;
QPen blackPen;
whiteBrush = QBrush(Qt::white);
imageBrush = QBrush(Qt::lightGray);
blackPen = QPen(Qt::black);
blackPen.setWidth(1);

QGraphicsItemGroup * cliGroup;
QGraphicsItemGroup * alfGroup;
cliGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup;
alfGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup;
scene->addItem(cliGroup);
scene->addItem(alfGroup);

QGraphicsPolygonItem *poly;
poly =  scene->addPolygon(polyF, blackPen, imageBrush);
cliGroup->addToGroup(poly);        //line it crashes on
```

I suspect it has something to do with creating the polygons on the scene and then adding them to the `QGraphicsItemGroup`, although I can't figure out how to alter this to work.  I've since resorted to a less elegant solution based on filtering the items in the scene based on type, but this is short-term and messy.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get a stack trace from crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`QGraphicsItemGroup`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitemgroup.html#addToGroup) documentation:

> There are two ways to construct an item group. **The easiest and most
>   common approach is to pass a list of items (e.g., all selected items)
>   to QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup(), which returns a new
>   QGraphicsItemGroup item.** The other approach is to manually construct a
>   QGraphicsItemGroup item, add it to the scene calling
>   QGraphicsScene::addItem(), and then add items to the group manually,
>   one at a time by calling addToGroup().

So as Pete suggested I would try the following:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> groupItems;
groupItems.append(poly); // add more items if you want
// Finally  construct the group
QGraphicsItemGroup * cliGroup = scene->createItemGroup(groupItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `new QGraphicsItemGroup`, use `QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup`.